# How can a docker container image be constructed “FROM scratch” that only has a python program and the basic python interpreter?

Tags: python, docker

No Alpine, Ubuntu, Debian, CentOS, yum, apt, apk, pip, etc. - just the bare minimum necessary to run a python program. Of course, it will probably have requirements that need to be installed also, from a requirements.txt file.

Just to be clear, a multistage build would be fine, as long as the final image contains the python program to run, the python interpreter and all its required libraries, etc., and the additional python requirements.

Comment: what do you mean by `No Alpine, Ubuntu, Debian, CentOS, etc` ? How do you plan to run something without a OS?

Comment: @Epsi95 You have a basic misunderstanding of what a container is. All you need to run a container is the kernel on the host, and the host support for containers (Docker, containerd, etc.)

Comment: I am not sure how exactly one could show effort to solve the problem here.

Comment: @newQOpenGLWidget - good point. I've searched the web a lot for an answer, but without success. I've tried building containers from scratch, and multistage, but it all seems kludgy and I still end up with (e.g.,) yum and/or pip installed (which I don't want also).

Comment: @Larry you answered your question.

Comment: @Epsi95 No, he wants only the python interpreter, not any additional packages.

Comment: @Epsi95 - so the answer is that what I want can't be accomplished? That's disappointing :(

Comment: I don't think it can be accomplished.

Comment: You should emphasize what you want to achieve. Do you want to reduce the image size in order to save space or do you want to minimize possible vulnerabilities?

Comment: @LydiavanDyke - good question - both actually. Probably more the former than the later, but once the unnecessary cruft is removed, the image will be more secure anyway.

Comment: @Larry I think your question is an interesting one. I started some local experiments to see how far I would get. Currently I am stuck with a problem related to the install path. Maybe the answers to my SO question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65869903/how-to-configure-shebang-line-of-internal-python-tools are of interest to you - as soon as there are any, that is....

Comment: @LydiavanDyke - thanks so much for the reference! Ironically, the developers use compiling our own Python as an argument against making our own containers, but I don't have a problem. there.

Answer (score 0):

If you really just want a simple and functional Python image, my recommendation would be to use one of the official Python images: https://hub.docker.com/_/python/

```
FROM python:latest
```

Comment: Those all have, for example, shells. I don't want shells for hackers to use, or package installers to have nefarious packages installed.

They're also very large for what's required - python:3.8-slim is 139MB

Comment: Yes, but this is the way... it’s not the OFFICIAL Python repo for nothing ;-) if you want something more lightweight you could build from a base alpine image but you would have to reinstall all the other necessary dependencies for Python to run... good luck with that.

Comment: python:latest is 311MB and includes such **useful** (not) things as bash and dash, mv, stty, grep, zless, sed, ls, ps to name a few - tools I really don't want to provide to hackers.

Comment: I _think_ it's the OFFICIAL Python image because it's very useful to _develop_ python programs.

Comment: I’m not sure what is your context but if security is your concern, you’re not addressing the problem in the right place. There’s probably many other things you should look into to secure your application rather than what is in your Docker image. Also you can use slim versions of the Python image

Comment: Alexis Rolland - thanks for the response. Size is the main concern, and python:3.8-slim has 7MB of useless binaries in /usr/bin, and I imaging a whole lot of unnecessary libraries. It's relatively trivial to make a statically compile Go binary and run that in a container with the image containing that binary _only_, so I'm attempting to do something similar with Python (but including the interpreter, of course).