# How to configure Shebang line of internal Python Tools

Tags: python, docker, makefile, configure

I am trying to build a minimal docker image, capable of nothing more but running the Python interpreter. During development I start from alpine, the final image will be build `FROM scratch`. I am working on a Linux Mint machine.

I am able to compile the Python compiler and install it into my current working directory like this:

```sh
cd Python-3.8.7
./configure --prefix=$PWD/../python
make install
```

However, I did not find out how to tweak the `--prefix` settings correctly so that the created shebangs will later work in the docker container.

First line of `./python/pip3` contains the absolute path of my host and reads

```
#!/home/orion/minimal_py_image/Python-3.8.7/../python/bin/python3.8
```

But it should read

```
#!/python/bin/python3.8
```

because `/python` is the location under which the Python interpreter will be found in the docker image.

How can I trick the `make install` script so that the final destination will be `/python/bin`?

I would like to keep the build contained in the current directory i.e. *not* using the folder `/python` on the host where I do the compilation.

**Additional Information**

Probably not directly relevant for this question but as reference: Here is the Dockerfile I am trying to get working:

```
FROM alpine

COPY python /python

COPY lib64/* /lib64/

ENV LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib64/:/lib64/:/python/lib
ENV PATH="${PATH}:/python/bin"
```

I am capable of running Python already with `docker run -it mini python3 -c "print('hello from python')"` but pip is not working yet due-to the wrong shebang.

Comment: Why not use an already built python alpine image?

Comment: Because it may become necessary in the project to not rely on external images due-to compliance regulations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A common convention in Autoconf-based build systems is to support a Make variable `DESTDIR`.  When you run `make install`, if `DESTDIR` is set, it actually installs into the configured directory under `DESTDIR`, but still built with the original path.  You can then create an archive of the target directory, or in a Docker context, use that directory as the build context.

```sh
cd Python-3.8.7
# Use the final install target as the --prefix
./configure --prefix=/python
# Installs into e.g. ../python/python/bin/python3.8
make install DESTDIR=../python

cd ../python
tar cvzf ../python.tar.gz .
```

You can see this variable [referenced in the Python Makefile](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/75e59a97f5d1fddb0c30ed9747b1b8cb84420a62/Makefile.pre.in#L1298) in many places.

Comment: Thank you very much, DESTDIR is what I was missing. For my setup the correct path is `make install DESTDIR=../` . With that additional line it works like a charm.